# Getting Bad method 405 response while trying to upload a file to Google Cloud Storage using SAP ui5

Tags: file-upload, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, sapui5

I am trying to upload a file to  Google Cloud Storage using a basic uploader in UI5.
When I am uploading the file, I am getting a 405 error in my response.

My controller code goes like this.

Please let me know if I am making any mistake anywhere.

```
    sap.ui.define(['sap/m/MessageToast','sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller'],
        function(MessageToast, Controller) {
        "use strict";

        return Controller.extend("sap.ui.unified.sample.FileUploaderBasic.Controller", {
            handleUploadComplete: function(oEvent) {
                var sResponse = oEvent.getParameter("response");
                if (sResponse) {
                    var sMsg = "";
                    var m = /^\[(\d\d\d)\]:(.*)$/.exec(sResponse);
                    if (m[1] == "200") {
                        sMsg = "Return Code: " + m[1] + "\n" + m[2] + "(Upload Success)";
                        oEvent.getSource().setValue("");
                    } else {
                        sMsg = "Return Code: " + m[1] + "\n" + m[2] + "(Upload Error)";
                    }

                    MessageToast.show(sMsg);
                }
            },

            handleUploadPress: function() {
                var oFileUploader = this.byId("fileUploader");
                var prop = oFileUploader.getValue();
                var path = oFileUploader.getUploadUrl();
                MessageToast.show(prop);
                MessageToast.show(path);
            //  var form = new FormData();
        //form.append("files", fileInput.files[0],"C:\Users\i347520\Desktop\pan.jpg");
                /*eslint-disable*/
                    var settings = {
      "url": "https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/testocr-1234/o?uploadType=media&name=prop"
      /*eslint-enable*/

    };

                oFileUploader.upload(settings);
            }
        });

    });
```

View:

```
    <mvc:View
        controllerName="sap.ui.unified.sample.FileUploaderBasic.Controller"
        xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
        xmlns:u="sap.ui.unified"
        xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
        xmlns="sap.m"
        class="viewPadding">
        <l:VerticalLayout>
            <u:FileUploader
                id="fileUploader"
                name="myFileUpload"
                uploadUrl="upload/"
                tooltip="Upload your file to the local server"
                uploadComplete="handleUploadComplete"/>
            <Button
                text="Upload File"
                press="handleUploadPress"/>
        </l:VerticalLayout>
    </mvc:View>
```

Comment: Is this the complete code? Where do you do the authentication? Where do you call `upload`?

Comment: The 405 response in [Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/status-codes#405_Method_Not_Allowed) is due to methodNotAllowed. Could you please share the error logs to investigate further?